# How to check if a game object has a component method in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, types

I am writing a method to check if a gameObject has a component.

Here it is:

```
public static bool HasComponent <T>(this GameObject obj)
{
    return obj.GetComponent<T>() != null;
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        if (gameObject.HasComponent<Rigidbody>())
        {
            print("Has a rigid body.");
            return;
        }

        print("Does not have rigid body.");
    }
}
```

The gameObject does NOT have a rigid body but it is still printing that it does have.

Comment: Try debug.logging the object name to make sure that you didn't accidentally place this script on another object, maybe?

Comment: I did, still prints that it has a rigidbody even though it does not.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. But I am able to replicate it on my PC! :O Good one. Debugging...

Comment: are you sure `GameObject` has a non-static public method of `HasComponent`. As you wrote it in your own class and trying to access it via gameObject?? If anybody can help me to understand this?? As he is getting proper logs :|, irrespective of he is calling it via gameObject which should not be and even using wrong signature (with void parameter)? :O

Comment: @JoeBlow OP mentioned "The gameObject does NOT have a rigid body but it is still printing that it does have." This is my question

Comment: Hi @HamzaHasan  ... the answer is that OP **made a syntax error** in the generic.  You have to have a **where** clause on the end or the return value will be nonsense from the call GetComponent<T>() .... it's returning I believe **whether it has *any component at all* attached**.  It's just a syntax error, Hamza.

Comment: @JoeBlow Ok, so it is returning a non null value. Is it because of this too?

Comment: Hi Hamza, sorry if I am not being clear.  I believe since "T" is basically "blank" ... you are asking it "GetComponent<>()".  Note there is ***NOTHING*** in the angle braces.  That means you are asking it ***IF IT HAS ANY COMPONENT AT ALL -- OF ANY TYPE WHATSOEVER.***  Am I explaining this ok?  Of course, it has to have components attached (of some type!) so it is returning "true".  Makes sense?

Comment: But note that it is  **really just "undefined" to not "where" the "T" there** -- the result is just nonsensical.  Just like any syntax error.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: wowwww... Now, all is well. Thank you so much @JoeBlow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is just...

```
public static bool HasComponent <T>(this GameObject obj) where T:Component
    {
    return obj.GetComponent<T>() != null;
    }
```

Note that you forgot the

## where T:Component

part of the first line!

With that syntax error, the extension is meaningless: it's always finding "some component" since T is "blank".

---

NOTE.

Explanation of "what the heck is an Extension".

For anyone reading this who is not familiar with categories in c# .. that is to say "Extensions" in c# ... here's a easy [tutorial](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1118868/view.html) ...

[image]

Extensions are critical in Unity.

You use them in pretty much every line of code.

**Basically in Unity you do almost everything in an Extension.**

Note that because extensions are so common, the OP did not even bother showing the wrapper class. Extensions always sit in a file like this:

```
public static class ExtensionsHandy
// The wrapper class name is actually irrelevant - it is not used at all.
// Choose any convenient name for the wrapper class.
    {
    
    public static bool HasComponent <T>(this GameObject obj) where T:Component
        {
        return obj.GetComponent<T>() != null;
        }
    
    public static bool IsNear(this float ff, float target)
        {
        float difference = ff-target;
        difference = Mathf.Abs(difference);
        if ( difference < 20f ) return true;
        else return false;
        }
    
    public static float Jiggle(this float ff)
        {
        return ff * UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.9f,1.1f);
        }
    
    public static Color Colored( this float alpha, int r, int g, int b )
        {
        return new Color(
            (float)r / 255f,
            (float)g / 255f,
            (float)b / 255f,
            alpha );
        }
  
    }
```

In the example I included three typical extensions.  Normally you'd have dozens or even hundreds of extensions in a project.

(You may prefer to group them in different `HandyExtensions` files, or just have one enormous `HandyExtensions` file.)

Every engineer and team has their own "common extensions" they use all the time.

Here's a typical [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087254/i-have-tears-because-i-cant-apply-dot-to-an-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp) about a subtlety of extensions in C#.

Note that in older languages you usually call extensions a "category".

In c# it is an "extension", but "category" or "extension" are both common.

As I say, you use these constantly in Unity.

---

*If you like that sort of thing, here's a beautiful one:*

```
// Here's an unbelievably useful array handling category for games!

public static T AnyOne<T>(this T[] ra) where T:class
    {
    int k = ra.Length;
    int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,k);
    return ra[r];
    }
```

Comment: Defaulters :P.. Similar users also exists in gamedev like [this one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/78138/alexandru-gurita) :D

Comment: You bet I am. Thanks for the help and sorry for not coming back. Unity answers solved it first so I never looked back here. Still, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found even easier way to achieve that,

```
 if (gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Rigidbody rb))
 {
     rb.useGravity = true;
 }
```

Read this article for more info: [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/454590/c-how-to-check-if-a-gameobject-contains-a-certain.html)